# Can't connect to Ubuntu server from OS X

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to connect to server on Ubuntu 14 from OS X terminal, but "Connection closed by 191.233.67.113"

I'm trying also to connect with that method `ssh -p 22 -v azureuser@djurahon.cloudapp.net`

it is the result:

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1, LibreSSL 2.1.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to djurahon.cloudapp.net [191.233.67.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Djurahon/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 191.233.67.113
```

What should I do, to connect to my server on Ubuntu 14 from Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "known_host" and connect again, like so to remove the host:

```
ssh-keygen -f "/PATH/TO/.ssh/known_hosts" -R IP_ADDRESS_OR_Host_name
```

Comment: I've tried to delete my ssh keys with that instruction
https://compassprogram.com/instructor-picks/deleting-known_hosts-file-for-ssh-authentication-errors-mac/
It did not help
also I try to generate new key with that instructions, http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-os-x-remove-known-host/  but it's also didn't help